# Job applications is not listed on my Stack Overflow Careers profile messages

Tags: bug, status-completed, jobs

Yesterday, I replied to a job on http://careers.stackoverflow.com. Today when I wanted to see the status of this application, I went to my Careers profile, clicked "messages" and realized there is no overview of my applications. I don't even have proof that my application has been sent. Am I missing something?

Comment: That's most likely a bug, edited to reflect it better.

Comment: Whenever an application has been submitted successfully, you will also get a confirmation email with the title "Application sent to <Company Name> - Stack Overflow Careers 2.0". So it sounds like you didn't get this confirmation email, correct?

Comment: This is correct, I did not receive an email. However, when I navigate to the job page, I do get a message saying I've applied.. So part of the process seemed to have worked. Just not all of it...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There was a delay with sending out your job application due to a bug in our system. We've taken care of the issue and your application has now been processed.

You should now be able to see the *Job Applications* section on the *messages* page where you can verify that your application has been sent out.

Thanks for bringing this to our attention and sorry for the delay!

Answer (score 1):

Once you're logged in, click `messages` up in the top right, then `job applications` in the left navigation. You should see a list of all the applications you've made through careers. Click on one to see the covering letter and CV you sent with the application. Of course, this won't work for jobs where the 'click here to apply' was a link to the employers separate system.

If you're thinking it isn't at all obvious that this is where sent applications can be viewed, I'd be inclined to agree.

Comment: Hi AakashM, Thank you for your response, I'm afraid the Job applications link is not showing in my messages page, just Messages and Send messages. I'm sure I've applied using the stackoverflow system: it offered me to create a CV using my stack overflow information. Could this mean that my job application has not reached my future employer?

Comment: Creating a CV from your SO info sounds like just setting up a *profile* on careers, rather than applying. What I mean about the application process is this: compare the apply button [here](http://careers.stackoverflow.com/jobs/36653) and the apply instructions [here](http://careers.stackoverflow.com/jobs/39263). Which kind was your application?

Comment: It was the first one: the button. There is a three step process, first I wrote a cover letter, after that, I've uploaded my CV, then I checked and confirmed. If I navigate to the job posting now, there is a message: You applied for this position on Aug 20. Good Luck!

Comment: Sounds like a problem then. Hopefully a Careers dev will be along soon...

Comment: The *Job Applications* section is hidden until the first job application has been submitted successfully. Looks like there was a problem with @ErikRos' application, that's why he currently still doesn't see the section.

Comment: So, what can I expect? Is someone able to check if my application is send? Is there another way I can apply or contact this organization?